# How to null the BooleanQuery object in lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

```
int length3 = CheckBoxList4.Items.Count;
int count = 0;         
for (int i = 0; i < length3; i++)
{
    BooleanQuery finalQuery1 = new BooleanQuery();                
    finalQuery1 = (BooleanQuery)Session["Luc_Query"];
    var query1 = new QueryParser("Industry", analyzer).Parse(CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text);
    finalQuery1.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);                
    hits = searcher.Search(finalQuery1);
    count = hits.Length();
    CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text = CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text +" " +count.ToString() ;
}
```

I tried to null the finalQuery1 but it repeats the added value from this `query(finalQuery1.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);)` .the methods I used to null the BooleanQuery is in below but its still not working.

```
finalQuery1 = (BooleanQuery)null;
finalQuery1=null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you don't want to modify the query which is stored in the `Session["Luc_Query"]`, just have it unmodified in every loop iteration.

Your code doesn't work cause you're modifying the same instance of the query in every iteration of the loop. You need to make the changes to the copy of the original query instead of changing the original query.

Try the code below:

```
int length3 = CheckBoxList4.Items.Count;
int count = 0;         
for (int i = 0; i < length3; i++)
{
    BooleanQuery finalQuery1 = (BooleanQuery)Session["Luc_Query"];
    finalQuery1 = (BooleanQuery)finalQuery1.Clone();
    var query1 = new QueryParser("Industry", analyzer).Parse(CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text);
    finalQuery1.Add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);                
    hits = searcher.Search(finalQuery1);
    count = hits.Length();
    CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text = CheckBoxList4.Items[i].Text + " " + count.ToString() ;
}
```